# Codeigniter if statement for multiple $this->input->post()

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

I have code which checks if user has entered data into the textfields:

```
if ( $this->input->post('current_password') || 
     $this->input->post('new_password') || 
     $this->input->post('repeat_password') ) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Why does the code above return `false`, but the code below returns `true`?

```
if ( $this->input->post('current_password') ) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: You will need to explain more about the logic of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
if ( ($this->input->post('current_password')) || 
     ($this->input->post('new_password')) || 
     ($this->input->post('repeat_password')) )
{
    return true;
} 
else 
{
    return false;
}
```

I think you needed to include additional `( )` with some space between the `||`

Comment: No because he closes off at the end but then maybe his logic wants that.

Comment: I doubt it - I can "see" what he is trying to do - and I think what I have proposed should fix it - but I'll guess we'll wait for Amirul to confirm

Comment: Yes, I think I missed the "()" which is very basic. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

These types of fields can only mean one thing. Am I correct you are using them for a user change password form? In that case:

```
//Below means that the user required to fill in all 3 of the fields. None of them must return false (be left blank)
if ($this->input->post('current_password') && $this->input->post('new_password') && $this->input->post('repeat_password') ) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

However, codeigniter supports a better way of checking form fields using the form validator:

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('newpass', 'New password', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
  $this->load->view('myform');
} else {
  $this->load->view('formsuccess');
}
```